# Read variables in output file & rsync

Tags: bash, read

Could someone perhaps give their advice on this.

I am wanting to take an output file from a mysql query ran:

```
$code    $IP
123456   192.168.26.176
10051    192.168.20.80
234567   192.168.26.178
```

and run it in command:

```
rsync -rvp *.$code.extension root@$IP:/path/of/dest
```

I am trying this:

```
while read -r line ; do echo 
"$SOURCE_TRANSMIT_DIR"*."$code".class.json 
"$DEST_HOST"@"$IP":"$DEST_TRANSMIT_DIR" ; done
```

Output I get is this:

```
/opt/file/outgoing/*.123456
10051
234567.class.json root@192.168.26.176
192.168.20.80
192.168.26.178:/opt/file/incoming/
```

Where I would like it to read like this in separate rsync commands:

```
rsync -rvp *.123456.extension root@192.168.26.176:/path/of/dest
rsync -rvp *.234567.extension root@192.168.20.80:/path/of/dest
rsync -rvp *.345678.extension root@192.168.26.178:/path/of/dest
```

Hopefully this explains better, sorry for the terrible explanation.

Comment: What is it you're actually wanting to do.  How do you get from a mysql query to a text file with what looks like shell variables in the first line, and from there to a bunch of files that you want to rsync to some hosts?  Is mysql actually relevant to the question or is it just a distraction?

Comment: The title says “two files” but is it actually two columns in one file? Or as output from a command?

Comment: The title mentions two files, but if you store the output of the MySQL query in a file (which is not necessary) then that's only one file. What's the second file?

Comment: What you say _in your question_ that you're trying cannot possibly produce the output you claim. Please tell us what is really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the result of your mysql query but you can execute it and parse with awk to print just what you want (see mysql option to avoid printing tuples and titles -raw or something like this )

```
mysql -printingoptions "your query" |awk '{print "rsync -rvp *."$1".extension  root@"$2":/path/of/dest"}'
```

You can pipe it to sh or bash then (commands |sh) to execute the rsync :)

Seems to be the easiest way to do that for me.

Comment: You should skip the first line (if it contains `$code    $IP`). Maybe a `NR>1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the output from your mysql-query through the following commands, it will give you the desired output. You can use this output to be evaluated, for example pipe it into a file and execute that file as a shell script.

```
mysql | grep -v '\$' | while read line; do echo "${line}" | sed 's#\(^[0-9]*\)[\ ]*\([0-9\.]*\)#rsync -rvp *.\1.extension root@\2:/path/of/dest#g'; done
```

Here are the details of the command:

```
mysql               # Your command with output (this is of course longer than this)
grep -v '\$'        # Exclude the header
while read line; do # Start a while-loop
echo "${line}"      # Echo the contents of the current line that we've read to the next command
# Regular expression to filter the number and the IP and add these to the command, they are held by the variables \1 \2.
sed 's#\(^[0-9]*\)[\ ]*\([0-9\.]*\)#rsync -rvp *.\1.extension root@\2:/path/of/dest#g'
done;               # Close the while loop
```

And the contents of the regexp explained:

```
(^[0-9]*\)   # From the beginning (^), zero or more (*) numerical [0-9] character
[\ ]*        # Zero or more (*) spaces. These are not in brackets, so they won't be matched into a variable.
([0-9\.]*    # Zero or more (*) numerical characters or points [0-9\.]
```

Comment: Drop the cat, it seems to be able to find its way in absolutely everywhere where it's not supposed to be.

Comment: It was just for developing purposes. As you don't know what commands you'll have to insert in the piping, I always start with the cat. Afterwards you can add the file information to the first command.

Comment: @Kusalananda cats are like that. However, depending on the scenario, the OP might want to use `unbuffer` and/or `xargs` or `parallel` to reduce dead times and improve performance.

Comment: That `while` loop doesn't appear to add any value. How about `mysql | sed '2,$s#...#...#g'` and dispense with the `grep` too.